# (DJANGO) How to display a list of categories and associated products on one page in django templete?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

**There are two models:**
''python

```
class Category(models.Model):

 name = models.CharField(_('category Name'), max_length=64)
...

 class Book(models.Model):

 title = models.CharField(_('book Title'), max_length=256)

 category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='category_book')
 ...
```

How to make the view one request to display in the template list of categories connected with the book. For example:

Fiction:

- book 1
- book 2

Story:

- book 3
- book 4
- book 5

etc..

Answer (score 0):

Personally I'd change the related name to `related_name='books'`

Then you can build a queryset along the lines of `Category.objects.prefetch_related('books')`

That could then be used in a detail view;

```py
class CategoryView(DetailView):

    model = Category

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.model.objects.prefetch_related('books')
```

Then in the template it'd be a loop along the lines of;

```
{% for cat in object_list %}
    {{ cat }}
    {% for book in cat.books.all %}
        {{ book }}
    {% endfor %}

{% endfor
```